# AutomateWoo plugin for WooCommerce: Creating a custom template issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have enabled AutomateWoo plugin for WooCommerce… To create a custom template, I followed the instructions on [AutomateWoo plugin Documentation > Email > Customizing your email design > Creating a custom template](https://woocommerce.com/document/automatewoo/email/customizing-your-email-design/#creating-a-custom-template):

- I have inserted the code into functions as instructed, in template [custom-3]
- I also registered the path like the instructions at the same level with the functions.php file as `templates/custom-1/…`

But when sending email nothing happens, only the original content has no WC header, footer, email, please help me with this problem.

In my functions.php file:

```php
add_filter( 'automatewoo_email_templates', 'my_automatewoo_email_templates' );

function my_automatewoo_email_templates( $templates ) {
    
    // SIMPLE
    // register a template by adding a slug and name to the $templates array
    $templates['custom-1'] = 'Custom Template #1';

    // ADVANCED
    // you can also create a template with a unique from name and from email by passing using the following array format 
    $templates['custom-2'] = array(
        'template_name' => 'Custom Template #2',
        'from_name' => 'AutomateWoo Custom',
        'from_email' => 'custom@automatewoo.com'
    );
    
    // SETTING A CUSTOM PATH
    // As of version 4.8, it's possible to set a custom template path
    $templates['custom-3'] = array(
        'template_name' => __( 'Custom Template with a custom path', 'my-plugin' ),
        'path'          => dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/custom-1'
    );

    return $templates;
}
```

Structure:

[image: Structure]

Result Test:

[image: Result Test]

If choose WC Default:

[image: Default template]

Comment: To make it work, you need to add both templates inside your child theme "`automatewoo`" *folder* > "`custom-email-templates`" *sub-folder* (but not in a "templates" folder).